# Autoit: access and simulate click link in iframe of website

Tags: javascript, dom, iframe, autoit

I am doing a project in autoit and I would like to read data of element in an iframe of this website (example http://worldoftanks.com/clanwars/maps/globalmap/?province=CA_92) but I need to click on the link at the below right of the iframe first ("landing..."), which is not a real link, to download the data that I need which is a table of teams join the tournament inside the iframe.

I know about the cross-restrick but this 2 sites is on the same domain so I think I could access but I only can access to the frame but not element inside it.

I wonder if anyone have suggestion because I stuck for almost a month on this problem. I am currently thinking about insert javascript into the HTML of the main page to get that information and pass it out as an element of main page

```
#include <MsgBoxConstants.au3>
#include <IE.au3>

$oIE=_IECreate('http://worldoftanks.com/clanwars/maps/globalmap/?province=CA_91')
Local $oFrames = _IEFrameGetCollection($oIE)
Local $iNumFrames = @extended
Local $sTxt = $iNumFrames & " frames found" & @CRLF & @CRLF
Local $oFrame = 0
    $oFrame = _IEFrameGetCollection($oIE, 0)
    $sTxt &= _IEPropertyGet($oFrame , "innerhtml") & @CRLF ; it crash right here or return code 80020009 if using error handle
MsgBox($MB_SYSTEMMODAL, "Frames Info", $sTxt)
```

Comment: so Matt, do you have any suggestion for my problem?

Answer (score 0):

`$oFrame` can be used exactly the same as a normal IE window, did you actually try any of the _IE* functions on it? Because they all work.

For example, here is the `_IEFrameGetCollection()` example merged with the `_IELinkGetCollection()` example from the helpfile.

```
#include <IE.au3>
#include <MsgBoxConstants.au3>

Local $oIE = _IE_Example("frameset")
Local $oFrames = _IEFrameGetCollection($oIE)
Local $iNumFrames = @extended
Local $sTxt = $iNumFrames & " frames found" & @CRLF & @CRLF
Local $oFrame = 0
For $i = 0 To ($iNumFrames - 1)
    $oFrame = _IEFrameGetCollection($oIE, $i)
    $sTxt &= _IEPropertyGet($oFrame, "innertext") & @CRLF
Next
;~ MsgBox($MB_SYSTEMMODAL, "Frames Info", $sTxt)

; Get the frame object we are interested in.
$oFrame = _IEFrameGetCollection($oIE, 1)

; Add a link as an example.
_IEBodyWriteHTML($oFrame, '<a href="#test">This is a link</a>')

; Get all links in that frame:
Local $oLinks = _IELinkGetCollection($oFrame, -1)
Local $iNumLinks = @extended

Local $sTxt = $iNumLinks & " links found" & @CRLF & @CRLF
For $oLink In $oLinks
    $sTxt &= $oLink.href & @CRLF
Next
MsgBox($MB_SYSTEMMODAL, "Link Info", $sTxt)

_IEQuit($oIE)
```

Comment: I will try it after i finish all my final exam

Comment: I used this      $oFrame = _IEFrameGetCollection($oIE, 0)      _IELinkGetCollection($oFrame,-1)  but I still get "Access is denied" code 80020009 right at the get link collection